# Getting pixel value of an image which is stored in an array of images using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an array of images and I need to get the pixel value at a co-ordinate of a particular image stored in that array. So far, my code is

```
for n = 1:5                                  % I have five images
     frame = sprintf('img (%d).jpg', n);
     image{n} = imread(frame);
end
image{1}(1, 1)                  % Co-ordinate is [1 1] and image is first element of array
```

I get the value as zero, even though the value expected is something else.
Can anyone just help me in this regard?

Comment: Did you try to check if `frame` contains a valid image name ?

Comment: `image{1}(1, 1)` is the correct syntax. 1. Use `clear all` command (just in case image already exists). 2. Verify `frame` contains a valid image name like Tony mentioned. `img (1).jpg` is not a sensible file name.